# flask app for object detection from webcam."flask run"(development) its working ok.But when i use uwsgi/nginx/any external its not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, flask, uwsgi

This is my index.html

```
    <img src="{{url_for('video_feed')}}" alt="video feed" width="80%" />
```

and below is my routing

```
@app.route("/video_feed")
def video_feed():
    return Response(
        myobjectdetectionFunc(), mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame"
    )
```

and myobjectdetectionFunc() returns

```
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)
        if ret:
            img = buffer.tobytes()
            # Yield the frame as a response to the client
            yield (b"--frame\r\n" b"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + img + b"\r\n")
```

These above code works perfectly when using flask run.but its not working when i use
"uwsgi dev.ini"
or when i deploy it using nginx or any external server other than developement server of flask.
I cant figure out what am i Missing?

i want to solve the above problem related to flask developement server.

Below is my full myobjectdetectionFunc();

```
def myobjectdetectionFunc():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # For Webcam
    cap.set(3, 1280)
    cap.set(4, 720);
    model = YOLO("assets/models/mymodel.pt");

    classNames = [..."classnames"
    ]
    myColor = (0, 0, 255)
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        results = model(img, stream=True)
        for r in results:
            boxes = r.boxes;


        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)
        if ret:
            img = buffer.tobytes()
            # Yield the frame as a response to the client
            yield (b"--frame\r\n" b"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + img + b"\r\n")

        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Please include the CLI result of your code "Not working" in the question.

Comment: you seem to be accessing your usb webcam. what makes you think the web server you dpeloy this to has a webcam attached to it? -- [mre] required.

Comment: @scr when i deploy it on nginx its shwoing bad gateway error only.